# WHERE clause in Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

```
String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_NAME, KEY_NUM };
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null, null, null, null);
```

This is the code I am using for returning those columns which match a particular string I have passed in i.e. name. However, this does not work. Also, If I replace the 'where' clause by null, all the rows are returned correctly. Please Help. Thanks!

The source table rows are thus

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "surveyString";
public static final String KEY_NUM = "numOfQuestions";
```

Comment: This isn't entirely related to your question, but any time I see string concatenation in a query, it's a strong indicator of it being vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Consider looking at some sort of prepared statement instead.

Comment: Prepared statements cannot be used for querying. The next best alternative is I think using rawQuery which doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that `name` really corresponds exactly to the value in your database ? If you replace `+ "=" + name` by `+ "LIKE %" + name + "% "`, is the result the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried put `'` between the variable?

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "='" + name + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the one I missed :)

Comment: @CL. I am just making the code work, for sql injection you can do something like `name.replace("'","\'")`

Comment: This is not [how SQL escapes quotes](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue). Using a parameter would have avoided this error.

Comment: @CL. I see, `A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal.` so just use `name.replace("'","''")`

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the where values into the "selectionArgs" parameter in your query.

`Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[]{name}, null, null, null);`

Comment: @OscarOrcas: Use [prepared statements](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) instead.

Comment: I think prepared statements are only used for statements (like CREATE, etc.) and not querying statements like SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addUserNotes(String notes,int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NOTES, notes);// Contact Phone Number
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    String s=Integer.toString(id);
    final String[] whereArgs = {s};
    db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, "id = ?", whereArgs);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```